# How to Reconnect Socket in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, sockets, socket.io

I am using socket.io for the socket connection. Problem is that when my app goes offline socket disconnects and when app again goes online socket doesn't connect. It doesn't fetches data from server side. I have created different class for the socket Handling. I am establishing connection in MainActivity and then using that in different actitvites like here in Display activity.

socket Handler

```
import io.socket.client.IO
import io.socket.client.Socket
import java.net.URISyntaxException
import android.util.Log

object SocketHandler {
    private const val SERVER_URL = "MY_URL"
    private lateinit var msocket: Socket

    @Synchronized
    fun setSocket() {
        try {
            val options = IO.Options()
            options.forceNew = true
            msocket = IO.socket(SERVER_URL, options)
        } catch (e: URISyntaxException) {
            Log.e("SocketHandler", "Error creating socket: $e")
        }
    }

    @Synchronized
    fun establishConnection() {
        msocket.connect()
        Log.e("SocketHandler", "Connection Established")
    }

    @Synchronized
    fun closeConnection() {
        msocket.disconnect()
        Log.e("SocketHandler", "Connection DISCONNECT")
    }

    @Synchronized
    fun getSocket(): Socket {
        return msocket
    }
}
```

```
class MainActivity : FragmentActivity() {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        '''
        //making socket connection
        SocketHandler.setSocket()
        SocketHandler.establishConnection()
        ...
   }
}
```

```
class Display : FragmentActivity() {

// using msocket to on and emit the data from the server side
var msocket = SocketHandler.getSocket()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display)
   }
}
```

I have used connectivity manager in my display acitvity to keep track over real-time internet connection. and when app reconnects i tried to call socket like  this

```
        SocketHandler.setSocket()
        SocketHandler.establishConnection()
        msocket = SocketHandler.getSocket()
```

In logcat it says socket connection is made but it doesn't recieves data from server side.

Comment: You can’t reconnect a TCP socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to trigger socket connectionevery time the app comes to the foreground, you should consider placing it in the `onResume()` method. Based on the android app lifecycle that should work.